# How to change/set/assign parameter's value for an entity query?

Tags: 8

Say you have an entity query which you're going to use in a loop so that only parameter(s) value(s) changes on every iteration. Is there a way to prepare this query and change the value of the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice examples in the comments on the api documention page for Entity queries https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x

One example assigns a value to a variable, then uses the variable in the query:

```
$value = 'some value';
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('entity_type');
$query->condition('field', $value);
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

In your loop you could re-assign the value as needed before executing the query.

Another example sets up some functions, so that might be an option and then your loop could call the function.

```
function someFunction($value) {

  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('entity_type');
  $query->condition('field', $value);
  $entity_ids = $query->execute();

}
```

Or you could clone the part that stays the same in your loop and alter the rest.  Using your code as an example...

```
$base_query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term'); 
$base_query->condition('vid', 'some_vocabulary'); 

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
  $query = clone $base_query;
  $query->condition('tid', $tids[$i]); 
  $query->execute(); 
  //...
}
```

Comment: All these examples recreate query from scratch. This doesn't look effective in case of a loop. Consider this example: 
`$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');`
`$query->condition('vid', 'some_vocabulary');`
`for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {`
  `$query->condition('tid', $tids[$i]);`
  `$query->execute();`
  `// ...`
`}`

P.S. Sorry for retarded code formatting, stackexchange is definitely an overthought thing, where is my code formatters damn it?

Comment: I updated the answer and added a section on cloning that should work for your scenario.

Comment: Yeah I see thank you. But yet this is not what I was looking for. Anyway thanks! At least this topic is covered now (on the internet).

Comment: Not sure what you were looking for but it's not supported to re-use an executed entity query. So cloning before executing it is the only option you have and this answer is correct